# Store multiple uploads by destination folder on MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

I saw a bunch of question similar to mine but not quite the same, in a way that I would have to change the way I'm currently storing the files on DB.

I have this one form on the first file (getPic.php):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="sendPics.php">
        <font size=4 color=DarkBlue><b>Choose 5 photos of your pet:</b></font><br><br>
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" /><br><br>
    <input name="send" type="submit" value="Upload photos">
```

And this on the other (sendPics.php)

```
$directory = "Images/";

if(!is_dir($directory)){ 
    echo "Folder does not exist";
}else{
    $file = isset($_FILES['file']) ? $_FILES['file'] : FALSE;
    for ($control = 0; $control < count($file['name']); $control++){

        $destiny = $directory."/".$file['name'][$control];
        if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'][$control], $destiny)){
            echo "Upload successful<br>"; 
        }else{
            echo "Error uploading the file";
        }   
    }
}

$destiny = "/".$destiny;
```

My table in MySQL looks like this:

```
Field           | Type       
----------------+------------
 idPetsPics     | int(11)    
 linkProfilePic | varchar(60)
 linkPhoto1     | varchar(60)
 linkPhoto2     | varchar(60)
 linkPhoto3     | varchar(60)
 linkPhoto4     | varchar(60)
 Pet_idPet      | int(11)      //(FK with PetsID on Pet's table)
```

So I need to store the path of the pics uploaded. Currently I'm only able to store the first one on the DB, though all the 5 pics gets to the destination folder successfully. For now I have:

```
$petID = $_SESSION['petID']; // obtained from a third file (queries to insert date into Pet)
require_once('dbConnection.php');


$insertPetPic = "INSERT INTO petPic (idPetsPics, linkProfilePic, Pet_idPet) VALUES (NULL, '$destiny', $petID[0])";
mysqli_query($conn, $insertFotoPet);
```

How can I change my code to store all the 5 paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each image that was moved successfully, you need to store the path to the image somewhere, for example in a `$paths` array:

```
$directory = "Images/";
$paths = array();

if(!is_dir($directory)){ 
    echo "Folder does not exist";
}else{
    $file = isset($_FILES['file']) ? $_FILES['file'] : FALSE;
    for ($control = 0; $control < count($file['name']); $control++){

        $destiny = $directory."/".$file['name'][$control];
        if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'][$control], $destiny)){
            $paths[] = $destiny;
            echo "Upload successful<br>"; 
        }else{
            echo "Error uploading the file";
        }   
    }
}
```

And then in your query you use the paths from the array:

```
$insertPetPic = "INSERT INTO petPic (idPetsPics, linkProfilePic, linkPhoto1, linkPhoto2, linkPhoto3, linkPhoto4, Pet_idPet) VALUES (NULL, '$paths[0]', '$paths[1]', '$paths[2]', '$paths[3]', '$paths[4]', $petID[0])";
```

Comment: That did it. I tried using an array before but couldn't get it to work. Thanks!